# Animating single pixels flying across screen using css3?

Tags: css, animation, pixel

So I was wondering if it was possible to animate a few single, white pixels to streak across the screen of a homepage I am building. I am a complete novice with css animations.

Basically I would love to have a few random pixels simply fly across the screen every few seconds. Is this even possible? Obviously I would have to play with the z-index to make sure they don't mess with the rest of the site.

Thanks in advance!

Kerr

Comment: You would need to use javascript / jquery as well to randomize a timer.

Comment: [It's certainly possible](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcy2grhn/3/); something I was playing with earlier. But it's not quick, and your request is pretty broad for Stack Overflow. Check out the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to improve your question.

Comment: Hey, yup. It probably is too general yeah, but I'm only looking to be nudged in the right direction. I'm in no rush and if it doesn't work then no worries. I just have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I made a sample of a rotating "pixel".

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/dazuku/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
var x=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$('#pixel').css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ x + 'deg)'});
x+=5;
}, 100);
});
```

Just to get you started. Change the pixel size and the transformation type to get the desired effect. If you want to get really fancy you can add a randomizer on the timer.

I didn't want to do it for you, just point you in the right direction. ;)

Comment: Aw cheers Gary! I'll give this a try. And thanks for not just spelling it out.